# Messaging Session object is not visible in Service Channel [Omni-Channel]

Tags: service-cloud-console, omnichannel, messagingsession

I am configuring Omni-Channel for messages (Whatsapp), I have connected my meta Account and whatsapp is connected and active, means if I send a message on the linked number, a messaging session record is created

In Omni-Channel the official documentation says, I need to create a Service Channel for "Messaging Session" so that it will count as in the capacity for the agents, but I cannot see this object in the list. Do we know why?

Official documentation - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.messaging_route_queues.htm&type=5

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The one that you are trying to configure is already configured so you arent able to see that object. Kindly check the below screenshot. The one with Messaging as Channel name.